# Material UI Table with Drop Down inside a column in one field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

Already Asked no answer for that question

Material UI Table with Drop Down inside a column.

Comment: your question is too vague. You must give the context of what you are trying to do. You should also (if possible) reproduce this issue for others who can help. You should also clarify the expected output. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TableCell>
    <Select>
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</TableCell>
```

Do you have some specific problem or issue?